# Where can i find [ BIlling address form] into panel admin?

Tags: magento-1.9

im looking for , billing adress form to edit order of inputs and lables but i dont know where is it?
[image]

i need modify order and add diferent label! 
Could u help me to find the file to modify! plz!!!

this is the code of link edit!!1

```
<div class="box-left">
    <!--Billing Address-->
    <div class="entry-edit">
        <div class="entry-edit-head">
            <h4 class="icon-head head-billing-address"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Billing Address') ?></h4>
            <div class="tools"><?php echo $this->getAddressEditLink($_order->getBillingAddress())?></div>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
            <address><?php echo $_order->getBillingAddress()->getFormated(true) ?></address>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but assuming you want to change the "label", you would likely achieve this by adding (or amending) a line to your translate.csv file.

A lot of the Magento labels allow you to use the translate.csv to easily accomplish this.

You can find the file in one of 2 locations normally, for example:

- /app/locale/LANGUAGE_FOLDER/translate.csv
- /app/design/frontend/THEME/default/translate/translate.csv

Hope this helps.

Comment: what I want to do is add a label to the second address field , for example . address # 2.
I can not find the file in which you can modify the form and add the label , do not want to translate the label or rename , opposite want to add a new label

Comment: Oh ok. I'm not entirey sure how to accomplish this without research, but the 2 URLS below might point you in the right direction: (http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/29/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address/) (http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2015/08/20/checkout-add-extra-address-field/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the form template starts here:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/address/form.phtml
```

It is calling the following code the build to form. I dug trough the code, and I think it's dynamically build. I couldn't find a template file just for this form.

```
  <?php echo $this->getForm()->toHtml() ?>
```

The header text is comming from the following block

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Address/Form.php
```

You can follow the class chain to find the `getForm` method. To see how the form is actally build.

**Bonus tip**: I found all this just by smart searching (unique values) in the github Magento 1 mirror. See exmaples below. This is a very easy way to find any unkown parts of the system. I use it all the time. It also works from the commandline (searching inside files).

[Example 1](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22Changing+address+information+will+not+recalculate+shipping%2C+tax+or+other+order+amount.%22&type=Code)

[Example 2](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22Order%20Address%20Information%22&type=Code)